# R studio - How to group data in a panel by year and sum them

Tags: r, data-visualization, panel-data

I have a panel dataset for 20 years and 10 companies.

For every company I have data on sales in Europe and the US.

I would like to plot the overall sales in Europe and the US for every year.

Basically, I need to sum the figure from every company for every year for the respective variable.

How should I do that?

Thanks everybody! I solved the problem usign group_by.

```
USsales <- data %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarize(tot_USsales = sum(USsales, na.rm = TRUE))

Europesales <- data %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarize(tot_Eursales = sum(Eursales, na.rm = TRUE))

netsales <- merge(Europesales, USsales, by="Year")
```

Then I just plot it with ggplot.

Thank you guys

Comment: Please include some data (a sample or some simulated data with the same structure) to allow us to make a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use R, you could do something like this:

```
require(dplyr)
require(magrittr)

OverallSalesEurope <- Dataset %>% 
                       filter(Region == "Europe") %>% 
                        group_by(Company, Year) %>% 
                         summarize(OverallSales = 
                                   sum(Sales, na.rm=TRUE)) 

OverallSalesUS <- Dataset %>% 
                       filter(Region == "US") %>% 
                        group_by(Company, Year) %>% 
                         summarize(OverallSales = 
                                   sum(Sales, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Of course, we don't know what your variables are named in your data set but the principles involved are illustrated in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have a data sample. Anyway this seems a simple usecase of `group_by` from `dplyr` library.

Basically group by `company`, `year` and `country`, then `sum`.

Here an example:

```
library(dyplr)
my_data %>% 
  group_by(company, year, country) %>% 
  summarise(mean_rev = mean(revenue))
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
# # Groups:   company, year [?]
# company year  country mean_rev
# <fct>   <fct> <fct>      <dbl>
# 1 A       2017  EU          74.1
# 2 A       2017  USA         59.6
# 3 A       2018  EU          64.7
# 4 A       2018  USA         79.8
# 5 B       2017  EU          79.8
# 6 B       2017  USA         79.1
# 7 B       2018  EU          81.0
# 8 B       2018  USA         74.7
```

Fake data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  company = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
  year = rep(c("2017","2018"), 10),
  country = c(rep("EU", 20), rep("USA", 20)),
  revenue = runif(40,50,100)
)
head(my_data)
#   company year country  revenue
# 1       A 2017      EU 78.08958
# 2       A 2018      EU 55.93207
# 3       A 2017      EU 57.55178
# 4       A 2018      EU 53.43027
# 5       A 2017      EU 50.02976
# 6       A 2018      EU 60.26888
```

Comment: It seems like you averaged by using the mean, so you are actually computing averages sales not overall sales? Also, Europe is not a country which is why Region might be a better name for the Country variable. Other than that, great answer!

Comment: Mine is just an example, the only important part is the grouping via `group_by`. You can change the `mean()` with `sum()` easily.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to plot this and not just summarize it.

Taking RLave dataset:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  company = c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10)),
  year = rep(c("2017","2018"), 10),
  country = c(rep("EU", 20), rep("USA", 20)),
  revenue = runif(40,50,100)
)
```

And the ggplot2 package:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(my_data,aes(x=country,y=revenue))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme_classic(base_size=12)+
  facet_wrap(~company+year)
```

You can build facets for each categories of companies, countries and years. Boxplots are a usual type of figures for this kind of data, the first and third quartiles are the ends of the box, the median is indicated with a vertical line in the interior of the box, and the minimum and maximum are the ends of the whiskers.

[image: Boxplots of revenues per country, for each year and each company. Made with ggplot2 and facet_wrap.]